# Grpc python (server/client) examples don't work

Tags: python, grpc

I'm trying to run the hello world python example from the grpc repo without success.

After starting the client it crashes with the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "greeter_client.py", line 34, in <module>
    run()
  File "greeter_client.py", line 30, in run
    response = stub.SayHello(helloworld_pb2.HelloRequest(name='you'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 507, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, deadline)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 455, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _Rendezvous(state, None, None, deadline)
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE, Connect Failed)>
```

Im quite sure I did run it months ago so maybe some update caused these problems?

pip show lists me following packets:

```
adium-theme-ubuntu (0.3.4)
enum34 (1.1.6)
futures (3.1.1)
grpcio (1.4.0)
grpcio-tools (1.4.0)
pip (9.0.1)
protobuf (3.3.0)
pygobject (3.20.0)
pyproj (1.9.5.1)
pyroute2 (0.4.18)
Pyste (0.9.10)
PyYAML (3.12)
pyzmq (16.0.2)
setuptools (36.2.5)
six (1.10.0)
unity-lens-photos (1.0)
wheel (0.29.0)
```

I already tried to use a random backoff to reconnect without success.

Comment: "quite sure I did run it months ago so maybe some update caused these" -- so restore your system to the state it was before and figure out what change it was that broke things

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment? Are you able to reproduce the difficulty you're having using a virtual environment? [If so, please share with us exactly what platform you're using (hardware (and version), operating system (and version), Python version, `pip` version, and so forth) and a sequence of commands to execute that displays the problem?](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html)